# My JSFiddle works but not in my system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Even though I have loaded jquery in , there is no response from my code.
but My JSfiddle works properly. Please help me where am I missing. No error caught on firefox console. I cannot figure out where am i missing. I am extremely new to js and jquery
JS fiddle setup is at http://jsfiddle.net/3Wdr3/1/

```
    <html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var counter = 2;
var availableTags = [
 "ActionScript",
 "AppleScript",
 "Asp",
 "BASIC",
 "C",
 "C++",
 "Clojure",
 "COBOL",
 "ColdFusion",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Groovy",
 "Haskell",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
 "Lisp",
 "Perl",
 "PHP",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala",
 "Scheme"];
$("#addButton").click(function () {
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
  .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

 var roleInput = $('<input/>',{
  type:'text',
  placeholder:'Role',
  name:'Role'+counter,
  id:'textbox' + counter
 });

 var searchInput = $('<input/>',{
  type:'text',
  placeholder:'search',
  name:'search'+counter,
  id:'se' + counter
 });

 var hidd=$('<input/>',{
  type:'hidden',
  name:'searchhid'+counter,
  id:'searchhid' + counter
 });


 newTextBoxDiv.append(roleInput).append(searchInput).append(hidd);
 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
 $('#se' + counter).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
 });
 counter++;
});
</script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-inline control-group">
  <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton' />
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's your jsfiddle setup?

Comment: you are loading the scripts too early before dom is rendered you need dom ready event

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: My bad.. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/3Wdr3/1/ edited the same in qn too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you wrap your calls to jQuery in a dom ready state.

```
$(function() {
   $("#addButton")...
});
```

JSFiddle does this for you.

This is important because the other elements aren't in the dom yet. So when you try to select them with jQuery, they don't exist and your script wont work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it little more. I am extremely new to jquery and js.. What should I change in my code to get it working ?

Comment: I have updated. but still CSS isnt applied. I am seeing traditional <ul><li> being on autocomplete suggestion. How can I get rid that like I am seeing in Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpZ3BWuJrsdjsGP9jNut?p=preview) you may understand why dom ready event is necessary

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//your js code
```

});

while in fiddle on left side in framework extension you can see that its set to onLoad which does things automatically